# Лента новостей в Android

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

Есть ли специальное событие у ScrollView, когда его полностью проматывают? Это нужно, чтобы новости подгружались постепенно, а не сразу.

Comment: Нет, такого события нет. Для список данных лучше использовать специальный виджет. RecyclerView например

Comment: @ЮрийСПб И там такое событие есть?

Comment: Нет, там тоже нет, просто так правильнее будет делать. В обоих случаях надо слушатель скрола вешать и в нём вычислять нужный момент. Для RecyclerView есть готовые примеры. Надо гуглить про `RecyclerView infiteScroll`